# Preventing Chrome Extension Uninstallation?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My company has Chrome with our custom extension running on windows machines.

Our goal is to launch chrome locally on our machines **with our extension running at all times**. Our users are constantly looking to uninstall our extension.

Our current approach is to utilize the [ExtensionInstallForceList](https://sites.google.com/site/lock5stat/offline-use/installing-for-all-users) registry key. This *sort of* works:

[image]

Right now, one can still click into C:\WM_0.0 and delete the folder. Once the folder is deleted, this extension is gone.

So we tried the following:

1. Create a windows account "Client"
2. Assign "Client" to "Client Group"
3. Change the permission `C:\WM_0.0` to `Deny Write`
4. Log out and login to the machine again as Client.

Once I login to my windows machine as `Client`, I can no longer load my extension:

[image]

I tried to change the folder's permission to `Full Control` for both `Users` and `Client Group` but I am still seeing this error in Chrome.

### 1. How can I load this extension successfully given my current set of circumstances?

### 2. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Setting aside the suspiciously malicious-looking intent of this exercise I'd say you are "almost there". All you need now is to have your `C:\WM_0.0` re-populated with a script that periodically copies the files into it if they were deleted :) As for the "better approach" - did you look into **why** is it that your users are trying to get rid of this extension? Maybe fix whatever is bothering them instead of shoving it down their throats. You may get better results with a carrot, not a stick in this situation.

Comment: This might be helpful [Manage Chrome apps by organizational unit](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6177431)

Comment: @Deliaz I just tried that approach. The GPO can still be disabled by removing the directory

Comment: Chrome creates `_metadata` directory upon first installation. The directory must be writable at this point. You can try propagating an existing _metadata directory though and see if it's recognized.

Comment: What are you putting in the ExtensionInstallForceList? Are you using the update manifest XML as the documentation indicates?